# Deleting the database when an Account is removed

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-account

My app uses the `SyncAdapter` pattern, holding user credentials using the `AccountManager` and a `ContentProvider` to store data in a db.

When the `account` gets removed I can remove the db using the approach explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5973098/119895). The db gets removed by doing:

```
boolean deleted = mContext.deleteDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
```

This works fine but when I do the login again everything is still there. It feels like the `ContentProvider` doesn't know that the db has been removed.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208863/119895), inazaruk says:

> You need to make sure you've killed the process that hosts
>   ContentProvider that uses that specific database file. And only than
>   delete it.

Killing the process to clear a db doesn't feel right.

Is there a better thing to do?

Comment: Why delete the database file? Isn't removing the data from the database enough?

Comment: @zapl: Yep. I could do something like `delete from table;`

Answer (score 2):

If I'd had to do that I would try it the following way:

add some `Uri` that when you insert or delete using that `Uri` triggers database deletion inside your `ContentProvider`. When deleting also clear all references to the `SQLiteDatabase` since it is possible that you can still access the old database file through that (If you delete a file in Linux and you have that file open you can still use it - it's just no longer accessible via the path).

By putting the deletion inside the `ContentProvider` you should be able to close the database connection and track the deletion state in a way that you know that you need to recreate the database file.

`ContentProviders` don't quit unless you kill your app so you probably have the same instance running and probably references to the old file as mentioned above